# SAP Kernel release in SAP

Tags: sap-basis, jco

Where is stored the Kernel release and SP level? Table or file (with constant path)?

I'm writing my program on JCo, I need to get this information from there.

Answer (score 1):

Table CVERS contains the kernel level (RELEASE) and patch level (EXTRELEASE) for the availables components.

Edit :

Analyzing the code source for the Status/Other Info gave me this line :

```
  CALL 'SAPCORE' ID 'ID' FIELD 'VERSION'
                 ID 'TABLE' FIELD kernel_version-*sys*.
```

in module "MODULE get_kinfo OUTPUT." in file LSHSYO01

where kernel_version is defined as

```
   DATA: BEGIN OF kernel_version OCCURS 0,
      key(21) TYPE c,
      data(69) TYPE c,
   END OF kernel_version.
```

after the call, table kernel_version-*sys* contains the following data

> ```
> SAP version        700
> operating system  AIX
> ...
> kernel release      700
> database library  OCI_102 (10.2.0.2.0)
> kernel compiled    AIX 2 5 005DD9CD4C00 May  2 2010 21:44:17
> kernel patch level  254
> supported SAP vers. 700
> ...
> hot package level 18
> ```

regards
Guillaume

Comment: CVERS table not contain Kernel

Comment: i thought that this was the SAP_BASIS component, sorry. Where can you see this value (ie System/Status ) ?

Comment: From System->Status click the "Other kernel info" button (between the Navigate and Cancel buttons).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see all that information you just select on the top menu SYSTEM inside you find STATUS.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use the command disp+work to check kernal release in sap